# How to fix home page rendering not working?

Tags: python, html, django, url, redirect

So I have urls to redirect the user to certain pages (form and home). I have one which you can click at the top of the home page which successfully redirects you to the form page and I have the same system to bring you back to the home page from the form page except it doesnt seem to  work and displays an error.

Edit : Error : The current path, home, matched the last one. (The last one being some random letters and numbers which probably means the path wasnt found)

Here is my home html file which works :

```html
<div class="page-title-add-button-div">
  <a class="page-title-add-button-link" href="/form"> + </a>
</div>
```

Here is my form file which doesnt work :

```html
<div class="page-title-add-button-div">
  <a class="page-title-add-button-link"  href="/home"> + </a>
</div>
```

Here is my views file :

```py
def home(request):
  litinfo = info.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'home.html', {'litinfo': litinfo})

def form(request):
  return render(request, 'form.html')
```

And finally here is my urls.py file :

```py
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.home, name='home'),
  path('form', views.form, name='form'),
]
```

Thanks in advance for any solutions, im new to django and just not too sure on how to fix this issue.

Edit : I've figured out that when I click on the URL in the form page it sends me to "http://(Numbers, not sure if confidential)/home" instead of "http://(Numbers, not sure if confidential)" which means it doesnt bring me back to the main page.

Comment: BTW for anyone wondering, the name of the project was just a random name my friends and I came up with but the project has nothing to do with it.

Comment: seems to be in the `urls.py`, line `path('form', views.form, name='form')`, you miss the slash symbol after 'form'. worked code is `path('form/, views.form, name='form')`

Comment: I dont think that fixed it because with that change I cant even open the form html file.

Comment: oh, I know where your problem is, cause your urlpattern use `''` for home router, so if you want to visit home router, just use `http://ip-or-urls-of-your-site:port/`to visit it

Comment: Oh ok, will do, sorry! Im new to stackoverflow and still learning all the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a path for `/home` in your ulrpatterns. Your error message says page not found (404) which means, it tried your to get the data in the path but the path doesn't exist.

Two ways to fix this:

1. In the `form.html` file change:

```
<div class="page-title-add-button-div">
  <a class="page-title-add-button-link"  href="/"> + </a>
</div>
```

2. In the urls.py file change:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.home, name='home'),
  path('form', views.form, name='form'),
  path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved this issue, I tested a few similar ideas but none of them worked so I ended up going on Stack Overflow but thx again for the answer!